# Remove strings containing only white spaces from list

Tags: python

How do I delete empty strings from a list? I tried like this:

```
starring = ['Vashu Bhagnani', 'Khemchand Bhagnani', ' ', 'Jacky Bhagnani', ' ', 'Prashant Shah', ' ']
output = filter(bool, starring)
```

Output I want:

```
['Vashu Bhagnani', 'Khemchand Bhagnani',  'Jacky Bhagnani',  'Prashant Shah']
```

But `output` ends up being the same as `input`. What's the correct function to pass to `filter`?

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://codepad.org/BzqIe31y), what is your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: What's wrong with what you posted? It works for me.

Comment: @Felix Kling. Code update. There is a space in `' '`.

Comment: Spaces evaluate to True, so if you don't want spaces you'll have to write a custom comparison function that deals with that or use a list comprehension.  Definitely look at the post that Blender mentioned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Only the empty string evaluates to `False` so you need to use `strip()` to remove any whitespace and we can then rely on non-blank strings being evaluated as true.

```
>>> starring = ['Vashu Bhagnani', 'Khemchand Bhagnani', ' ', 'Jacky Bhagnani', ' ', 'Prashant Shah', ' ']                                      
>>> starring = filter(lambda name: name.strip(), starring)
>>> starring
['Vashu Bhagnani', 'Khemchand Bhagnani', 'Jacky Bhagnani', 'Prashant Shah']
```

Although a list comprehension might be easier:

```
>>> [name for name in starring if name.strip()]
['Vashu Bhagnani', 'Khemchand Bhagnani', 'Jacky Bhagnani', 'Prashant Shah']
```

Comment: That's because you missed the space in the third element in the original string. That element is not an empty string.

Comment: @MartinFrost - That was from before the question was editing but the posted code worked either way.  Now updated in any case.

Comment: You do not need the `bool`; that is, `filter(lambda name: name.strip(), starring)` works. The result is the same either way, though.

Comment: You don't need lambda either, you can just `filter(str.strip, starring)`. ;-)

Comment: @DaveWebb In your second code snippet, why would `name.strip()` return a `True` or `False`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be non-empty, rather than _non-blank_?

Answer (score 9):

You can remove trailing and leading white spaces, which will result in an empty string if it only contains those.

List comprehension:

```
l = [x for x in l if x.strip()]
```

With `filter` and [`operator.methodcaller` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
l = filter(operator.methodcaller('strip'), l)
```

or simpler:

```
l = filter(str.strip, l)
```

`operator.methodcaller` would be the only way if you'd want to pass additional arguments to the method.

Comment: I like `l = filter(operator.methodcaller('strip'), l)` Thanks

Comment: Is using `operator.methodcaller('strip')` preferred over just doing `str.strip` (i.e., instead of doing `filter(str.strip, l)`)?

Comment: @David: I didn't know that `str.strip` works but thinking about it, seems to be reasonable. Thanks! I guess you would use `operator.methodcaller` when you want to pass additional arguments.

Comment: Also `operator.methodcaller` will not fail on unicode strings and other stuff in the list, i.e. it is better suited for pythonic duck-typing model.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = ['Vashu Bhagnani', 'Khemchand Bhagnani', '', 'Jacky Bhagnani', '', 'Prashant Shah', '']
[a for a in s if len(a) > 0]
```

Comment: this doesn't work on whitespace strings, which should be removed.