# Python: how to get correct list when split?

Tags: python

In test.txt, I have 2 lines of sentences.

```
The heart was made to be broken.
There is no surprise more magical than the surprise of being loved.
```

The code:

```
import re
file = open('/test.txt','r')#specify file to open
data = file.readlines()
file.close()
for line in data:
    line_split = re.split(r'[ \t\n\r, ]+',line)
    print line_split
```

Results from the codes:

```
['The', 'heart', 'was', 'made', 'to', 'be', 'broken.', '']
['There', 'is', 'no', 'surprise', 'more', 'magical', 'than', 'the', 'surprise', 'of', 'being', 'loved.']
```

How to get only word print out? (see the first sentence) Expect result:

```
['The', 'heart', 'was', 'made', 'to', 'be', 'broken.']
['There', 'is', 'no', 'surprise', 'more', 'magical', 'than', 'the', 'surprise', 'of', 'being', 'loved.']
```

Any advice?

Comment: It would be more productive if you told us what you're actually trying to do, instead of posting nearly identical questions. Also, `[ \t\n\r, ]` doesn't make sense, you want `[\s,]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `split` to match the delimiters, you can use `findall` with the negated regular expression to match the parts you want to keep:

```
line_split = re.findall(r'[^ \t\n\r., ]+',line)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/OV2dq)

Comment: OMG! it my fault...I forget ^... I am so sorry.

Comment: @ThanaDaray: Don't worry. It's probably my fault for not making the answer clear enough. Sorry!

Comment: +1, this is more elegant than my answer, but do take a look at mine for the other comments I made.

Answer (score 1):

To fix, with a few other changes, explained further on:

```
import re

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line_split = filter(bool, re.split(r'[ \t\n\r, ]+', line))
        print(line_split)
```

Here we use a [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) to remove any empty strings from the result.

Note my use of [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file. This is more readable and handles closing the file for you, even on exceptions.

We also loop directly over the file - this is a better idea as it doesn't load the entire file into memory at once, which is not needed and could cause problems with big files.

Comment: Except that this does not split on, and drop, commas.

Comment: @delnan Ugh, should have read that more closely on my part, still, an easy fix.

Comment: Unfortunately not. `str.split()` skips over multiple consecutive whitespace characters, but if you give it explicit separators, consecutive separators result in empty strings in the output (i.e. `"foo, bar"` would be split into `['foo', '', 'bar']`). Yes, that's ugly.

Comment: @delnan You know what, I was sure that was not the way it functions, apparently my memory is poor, I'll change it to a regex solution. Edit: Updated, and this time I tested it - definitely works.

Comment: This can still give empty "words" if the line ends with a comma: http://ideone.com/rci8S

Comment: @MarkByers Of course it does. I'm doing well here - although I'm going to blame the asker a little for providing a test case that doesn't cover the wanted functionality.

Comment: Yes, I also forget it all the time. What's worse, when looking it up to be sure, I remembered `str.split` only accepts a single separator string, not a variety of characters which may each split. Meaning, your original code would only split on the 5-char sequence `\t\n\t, `. And they say Python makes string handling easy... well, easier than C I suppose.

Comment: @delnan Yeah, I noticed that as soon as I tested it. As I say, I was sure I remember that being the functionality. Maybe that's PHP or something from the past, I don't know. To be fair, splitting on multiple character strings is probably something I use more than on a selection of characters. Anyway, this version should work. Probably not the most elegant, but I'll leave it up for the other advice.

Comment: +1 for fixing it (after a few attempts) and some other good pieces of advice. PS: you can also [remove empty strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings) slightly more concisely using filter, though I'm not 100% convinced that it's better to use this trick rather than the more simple list comprehension you've used.

Comment: @MarkByers Yeah, I've never been a functional programming man, so `map()` and `filter()` never really appeal to me. In this situation, you would need a `lambda` which pretty much kills any performance or readability gains, in my opinion. It's definitely an option here though, there isn't much in it, as `[x for x in ...]` is always a bit ugly.

Comment: @Lattyware: Actually if you read the top voted answer on the [question I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings), you can see that you don't actually need a lambda because you can just use the trick `filter(None, x)`.

Comment: @MarkByers Oh, I didn't see that link. That is considerably nicer, although I feel `filter(bool, xs)` is more obvious (and I should have thought of it earlier, not doing well on this one at all).

Answer (score 1):

```
words = re.compile(r"[\w']+").findall(yourString)
```

Demo

```
>>> yourString = "Mary's lamb was white as snow."
["Mary's", 'lamb', 'was', 'white', 'as', 'snow']
```

If you really do want periods, you can add those as `[\w'\.]`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: with open('test.txt','r') as f:
   ...:     lines = f.readlines()
   ...:

In [3]: words = [l.split() for l in lines]

In [4]: words
Out[4]:
[['The', 'heart', 'was', 'made', 'to', 'be', 'broken.'],
 ['There',
  'is',
  'no',
  'surprise',
  'more',
  'magical',
  'than',
  'the',
  'surprise',
  'of',
  'being',
  'loved.']]
```