# Last element in python list, created by splitting a string is empty

Tags: python, string, list, split, strip

So I have a string which I need to parse. The string contains a number of words, separated by a hyphen (`-`). The string also ends with a hyphen.

For example `one-two-three-`.

Now, if I want to look at the words on their own, I split up the string to a list.

```
wordstring = "one-two-three-"
wordlist = wordstring.split('-')

for i in range(0, len(wordlist)):
     print(wordlist[i])
```

Output

```
one
two
three
#empty element
```

What I don't understand is, why in the resulting list, the final element is an empty string.
How can I omit this empty element?

Should I simply truncate the list or is there a better way to split the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python split function -avoids last empy space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780423/python-split-function-avoids-last-empy-space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an empty string because the split on the last `-` character produces an empty string on the RHS. You can strip all `'-'` characters from the string before splitting:

```
wordlist = wordstring.strip('-').split('-')
```

Answer (score 3):

If the final element is *always* a `-` character, you can omit it by using `[:-1]` which grabs all the elements of the string besides the last character.

Then, proceed to `split` it as you did:

```
wordlist = wordstring[:-1].split('-')
print(wordlist)
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to do this :

```
import re
wordlist = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+(?=-)", wordstring)
```

Output :

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I'd just use `"[^-]+"` instead. We don't know what are the "legal" characters, just that it's not a `-`.

Comment: This answer also handles the `wordstring = "one-two---three-"` case correctly (assuming that in this case there should be no empty strings either)

Comment: Sure, with "this" I meant _this answer_, not _my suggestion_.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) built-in function of Python before splitting your String. E.g:

```
wordstring = "one-two-three-"
wordlist = wordstring.strip('-').split('-')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `.split()` is assuming there is another element after the last `-` but it is obviously a blank entry.

Are you open to removing the dash in `wordstring` before splitting it?

```
wordstring = "one-two-three-"
wordlist = wordstring[:-1].split('-')
print wordlist

OUT: 'one-two-three'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> ...
>   If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')` returns `['1', '', '2']`).
>   ...

If you know your strings will always end in `'-'`, then just remove the last one by doing `wordlist.pop()`.

If you need something more complicated you may want to learn about [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just for the variaty of options:

```
wordlist = [x for x in wordstring.split('-') if x]
```

Note that the above also handles cases such as: `wordstring = "one-two--three-"` (double hyphen)

Comment: An inefficient option

Comment: @Chris_Rands That is why the disclaimer is there.

Comment: IMO not worth listing worse alternatives to existing solutions, but here's another then: `wordstring.replace('-','\n').splitlines()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands 1) you are free to dv if it messes up with your aesthetics. 2) this comprehension might no be so interesting here because this is a very simple case but the construct `[x for x in y if f(x)]` is valuable in many cases and often encountered.

Comment: I'm not gonna dv but 2) is irrelevant to *this* question

Answer (score 1):

First strip() then split()

```
wordstring = "one-two-three-"
x = wordstring.strip('-')
y  = x.split('-')

for word in y:
    print word
```

Comment: `[i for i in wordlist]` this is the same as `wordlist`

Comment: `[i for i in y]` is also the same as `y` ☺ and so on.. Just remove this line entirely

Answer (score -1):

Strip/trim the string before splitting. This way you will remove the trailing "\n" and you should be fine.