# What is the most pythonic way to filter list from number?

Tags: python, list

i have this :

```
['SPRD', '60', 'p25']
```

I want to generate that :

```
['SPRD', 'p']
```

What is the most pythonic way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: use regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [25]: l = ['SPRD', '60', 'p25']

In [26]: filter(None,(s.translate(None,'1234567890') for s in l))
Out[26]: ['SPRD', 'p']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
digits_stripped = (s.translate(None, '0123456789') for s in input_list)
without_blanks = [s for s in digits_stripped if s]
```

(Note that if you happen to be using a Python older than 2.6, you'll need to use `string.maketrans('', '')` instead of `None` as the first argument to `translate()`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [37]: l = []

In [38]: p = "[a-zA-Z]*"

In [39]: p1 = re.compile(p)

In [40]: for i in  ['SPRD', '60', 'p25']:
   ....:     if p1.match(i):
   ....:         l.append(p1.match(i).group())
   ....:

In [41]: [x for x in l if x]
Out[41]: ['SPRD', 'p']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
filter(None, [re.sub("\d+", "", f) for f in input_list])
```

I believe this is quite pythonic, although it does require regex and is not as efficient as other answers. First, all digits are removed from words, then any emptystrings are removed from the list.

Comment: List comprehensions are generally preferred over `filter`.

Comment: They may be preferred, but are a lot slower: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings.

Comment: @Jaapsneep -- No, they are not... The performance is pretty much the same, just `timeit`...(while `filter` with `None` is one of the few cases I would use it over a comprehension...)

Comment: I didn't mean slower in general, but in the specific case that you would want to check elements in a list for their truth values (not equal to emptystring). See the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generation expression, regular expressions, a list comprehensions:

```
import re
[s for s in (re.sub("[0-9]*", "", s) for s in l) if s]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your lists only contain strings and you only want to filter out numbers, this, however clunky, may work too:

```
def filter_text(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return ''
    except ValueError:
        return x

l = ['SPRD', '60', 'p25']
newlist = []
for x in l:
     newlist.append(''.join([filter_text(y) for y in x]))
newlist = [x for x in newlist if x != '']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-in-python), casting should be faster and "prettier" than regex or string operations.

The best way to do this then should look something like this:

```py
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

#with list comprehension
def filter_number(seq):
    return [item for item in seq if not is_number(item)]

#with a generator
def filter_number_generator(seq):
    for item in seq:
        if not is_number(item): yeld item
```

If your goal is to have a copy of the list in memory, you should use the list comprehension method. Now if you want to iterate over each non-number item in the list efficiently, the generator allows you to do something like:

```
for non_number in filter_number_generator(l)
```