# How to remove all spaces in the strings in list

Tags: python

My list is like this,

```
mylist=[ " ","abc","bgt","llko","    ","hhyt","  ","      ","iuyt"]
```

How to remove all spaces containing strings inside this list?

Comment: By empty do you mean you include strings containing only spaces?

Comment: Ya...My program reads a file and takes each line and splits.. so in list it has empty strings, i mean spaces

Comment: I don't know why noone suggested this, but the following seems to be the fastest among the top answers - `[elem for elem in mylist if not elem.isspace()]`

Comment: isspace() is supported? I didnt know... Thank you between!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
 new_list = [elem for elem in mylist if elem.strip()]
```

Using `strip()` guarantees that even strings containing only multiple spaces will be removed.

Comment: ...or just `[elem for elem in mylist if elem.strip()]`

Answer (score 9):

Use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) with *unbound method* [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.strip).

### Python 2.x

```
>>> mylist=[ " ","abc","bgt","llko"," ","hhyt"," "," ","iuyt"]
>>> filter(str.strip, mylist)
['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
```

### Python 3.x

```
>>> mylist=[ " ","abc","bgt","llko"," ","hhyt"," "," ","iuyt"]
>>> list(filter(str.strip, mylist))
['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use filter with `None`.

```
filter(None, mylist)
```

If by empty strings you mean strings containing only whitespace characters, then you should use:

```
filter(str.strip, mylist)
```

Examples:

```
>>> filter(None, ['', 'abc', 'bgt', 'llko', '', 'hhyt', '', '', 'iuyt'])
['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
>>> filter(str.strip, [' ', 'abc', 'bgt', 'llko', ' ', 'hhyt', ' ', ' ', 'iuyt'])
['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `filter(lambda x: x.strip(), mylist)`:

```
>>> mylist=[ " ","abc","bgt","llko"," ","hhyt"," "," ","iuyt"]
>>>
>>> filter(lambda x: x.strip(), mylist)
['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
>>>
>>> mylist=[ " ","abc","bgt","llko","    ","hhyt","  ","      ","iuyt"]
>>>
>>> filter(lambda x: x.strip(), mylist)
['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = [x for x in [ " ","abc","bgt","llko"," ","hhyt"," "," ","iuyt"] if x]
```

... List comprehension with "if" clause and, in this case, relying on the fact that Python considers empty strings (and empty containers) to be "False" in boolean contexts.

If by "empty" you mean zero-length or containing only spaces then you can change the `if` clause to read `if x.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
>>> mylist=[ " ","abc","bgt","llko"," ","hhyt"," "," ","iuyt"]
>>> new_list = [e for e in mylist if len(e.strip())!=0]
>>> new_list
      ['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
```

Answer (score 1):

The method isalpha() checks whether the string consists of alphabetic characters only:

```
mylist=[ " ","abc","bgt","llko"," ","hhyt"," "," ","iuyt"] 
mylist = [word for word in mylist if word.isalpha()]
print mylist

Output:['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [s for s in mylist if str is not " "]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["first", "", "second"]
[x for x in list if x]
```

Output: ['first', 'second']

Shortened as suggested,the same question given below

[Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> mylist=[ " ","abc","bgt","llko"," ","hhyt"," "," ","iuyt"]
>>> [i for i in mylist if i.strip() != '']
['abc', 'bgt', 'llko', 'hhyt', 'iuyt']
```