# Removing empty strings from a list in python

Tags: python, regex, split

I need to split a string. I am using this:

```
def ParseStringFile(string):
p = re.compile('\W+')
result = p.split(string)
```

But I have an error: my result has two empty strings (''), one before 'Лев'. How do I get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: No. It works correctly. The empty string is due to the extra new line at the beginning of the string.

Comment: nhahtdh I need to delete first and last empty (' ') elements of list, before using split?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As nhahtdh pointed out, the empty string is expected since there's a `\n` at the start and end of the string, but if they bother you, you can `filter` them very quickly and efficiently.

```
>>> filter(None, ['', 'text', 'more text', ''])
['text', 'more text']
```

`filter` usually takes a callable function as first argument and creates a list with all elements removed for which `function(element)` returns `False`. Here `None` is given, which triggers a special case: The element is removed if `bool(element)` is false. As `bool('')` is false, it gets removed.

Also see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all newlines from the string before matching it:

```
p.split(string.strip('\n'))
```

Alternatively, split the string and then remove the first and last element:

```
result = p.split(string)[1:-1]
```

The `[1:-1]` takes a copy of the result and includes all indexes starting at 1 (i.e. removing the first element), and ending at -2 (i.e. the second to last element. The second index is exclusive)

A longer and less elegant alternative would be to modify the list in-place:

```
result = p.split(string)
del result[-1]   # remove last element
del result[0]    # remove first element
```

Note that in these two solutions the first and last element *must* be the empty string. If sometimes the input doesn't contain these empty strings at the beginning or end, then they will misbehave. However they are also the *fastest* solutions.

If you want to remove *all* empty strings in the result, even if they happen inside the list of results you can use a list-comprehension:

```
[word for word in p.split(string) if word]
```

Comment: One of the few instances where `filter` actually beats out list comps actually. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I doubt speed matters in this case, but readability does and I prefer the list-comprehension. Also in python3 `filter` doesn't produce a list, which might or might not be what the OP wants. Also, if speed matters using the `[1:-1]` is much faster because it avoids all the truth tests altogether.

Comment: Reasonable, just thought you might like to know. As someone who generally thinks things like `filter`and `map` should rarely be used, this is one case where I've really got to argue for the `filter`solution. 5x speed increase, and intuitively, you are filtering the list, but both are certainly accurate solutions.

[1:-1] seems dangerously brittle to me.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus That answer is from 2010. On my machine I get quite different results, although `filter` with `None` is (obviously) still the fastest (By about 2.8x on python2 and about 85% on python3). It seems like during the last 4 years there was a pretty good job in optimizing the interpreter.

Comment: What about speed in filter solution? I don't want use [1;-1] solution becouse text don't have to have ' ' symbols, all sites various

Comment: Ah, that's great news! I just ran it on my machine and got similar results.

Comment: @Denis That is the speed in the filter solution, still about 3x faster in python 2, with a more modest speed increase in python 3 (not sure which you're using.)

Comment: Optimization it's very interesting for me, if it's not remove all readability

Comment: i'am using python 3.3