# Finding length of line

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file like following

```
,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
0,7498.0,7499.0,,,,,,,,,,
1,7445.0,7456.0,,,,,,,,,,
2,7412.0,7413.0,7414.0,,,,,,,,,
3,7338.0,7412.0,7413.0,7414.0,,,,,,,,
4,7261.0,7021.0,,,,,,,,,,
```

I need to get the length of each line like following. How to do this with python?

```
2
2
3
4
2
```

This is not going to work since it counts all line splits.

```
f = open('myfile','r')
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    li = line.split(',')
    print len(li)
```

Comment: What is the length of a line here then? Do you mean the number of *non-empty* columns, not counting the first?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, Yes, number of non-empty columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apparently want to count the *non-empty* columns.

First, use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html); no need to reinvent the CSV-reading wheel. Then filter out empty columns and count:

```
import csv

with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # count non-empty cells, but ignore the first
        nonempty = [cell for cell in row[1:] if cell]
        print len(nonempty)
```

Comment: Excellant, Thank you very much :)

Comment: `nonempty = sum(bool(cell) for cell in row[1:])` would be a little shorter and avoid creating a temporary list.

Comment: @martineau: but perhaps the OP wants to make use of the non-empty cells for other things as well?

Comment: Either way the values of all the cells are still available in the original `row` list before the next one is read by the reader. If the OP wants to do additional processing of non-empty ones, that probably ought to be done with a regular `for cell in row[1:]:` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
>>> len(list(filter(bool, ['a', 'b', '', ''])))
2
```

More about it in another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings).

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("myfile") as i:
    reader = csv.reader(i)
    for line in reader:
        print(len([x for x in line if x != ""]))
```

Output:

```
13
3
3
4
5
3
```