# replacing certain expressions in file but only one time

Tags: python

I extracted some expressions from a file and I want to insert these expressions in the same file but under different format, like between brackets. My problem is that I want for every expression only one replacing. 
the file looks like this

```
file = """he is a good man
she is a beautiful woman
this is a clever student
he is a bad neighbour
they are bad men
She is very beautiful"""
```

and the expressions are like this

```
ex = """ good, clever, beautiful, bad,"""
```

the code used is

```
adj =  ex.split(",") 
for a in adj:
  if a in file:
     file = file.replace(a, ' ' +'[[' + a + ']]')
print file
```

this gives the following output:

```
he is a  [[good]] man [[
]]she is a [[ beautiful]] woman [[
]]this is a [[ clever]] student [[
]]he is a [[ bad]] neighbour [[
]]they are [[ bad]] men [[
]]She is very [[ beautiful]] [[
]] [[
]]
```

while the expected output is

```
he is a  [[good]] man 
she is a [[ beautiful]] woman 
this is a [[ clever]] student 
he is a [[ bad]] neighbour 
they are bad men # so here "bad" will not be replaced because there is another 'bad' replaced 
She is very beautiful # and here 'beautiful' will not be replaced like 'bad'
```

Comment: Simply `strip()` the line before you `split()` it, and you're free to go. Also check for empty `a`'s in `adj` while iterating, so you may skip them if they show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If file content is stored as string

the replace method of a string also takes in a third optional argument called `max`.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

This will allow you to choose the occurrence of a word that you want to replace.

for instance,

```
>>> "he is a good man, and a good husband".replace('good', '[[ good ]]', 1)
'he is a [[ good ]] man, and a good husband'
>>>
```

Hang on, im working on your example now.

### Example 2 : Read from a file, one line at a time.

In the above method, I will assume that you have read the file and store its content as a single string . In the 2nd answer below, I will show you how you may implement your code to solve your problem

#### Assuming you have a file `testfile.txt` with the following content :

```
he is a good man
she is a beautiful woman
this is a clever student
he is a bad neighbour
they are bad men
She is very beautifu
```

#### Here is your python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# your expression 
ex = """ good, clever, beautiful, bad,"""

# list comprehension to clean up your expression, 
# first by spliting it by comma and then remove anything that is just a empty
wanted_terms = [x.strip() for x in ex.split(',') if x.strip() != '']

## read file using with statement
with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        ## for each wanted terms check if they exist in the line 
        for x in wanted_terms:
            if x in line:
                ## I prefer to use string format here.
                #replacement = "[[ %s ]]" % x 
                #line = line.replace(x, replacement, 1)

                ## if term exist, do replacement. Use max =1 to ensure it replace only the first instance.
                line = line.replace(x, '[[' + x +']]', 1 )
                ## remove it from term list so that in future, it will replace any new occurence
                wanted_terms.remove(x)
```

Let me know you find this useful or if there are any other comments,

Cheers,
Biobirdman

Answer (score 0):

biobirdman seems to have a good solution, so use that for the correct thing.  My post here is just to explain what went wrong.  When you did:

```
ex = """ good, clever, beautiful, bad,"""
adj =  ex.split(",")
```

You got something other than what you thought

```
print adj
[' good', ' clever', ' beautiful', ' bad', '']
```

I don't know if you mean to have a space before each one string, but you almost certainly don't mean to have a '' at the end.  In fact, I think you didn't have this for your example, otherwise you'd get a different bad behavior.  What I think you had was a new line character at the end of ex.  So that '' that's showing up was actually a newline in your attempt.

So it matched all the ones you expected, plus all the newlines for you.  For anyone using the code you posted, they'll get a match between every pair of characters.

```
[[]]h [[]]e [[]]  [[]]i [[]]s [[]]  [[]]a  ........
```

TO fix: get rid of the newline.  Eliminate the extra spaces.  How?  Take a look at strip.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes to your code. Avoiding a empty string in `adj` and removing leading whitespaces when you replace `word` with `[[word]]`. `word` has values like " beautiful", " clever" in your code.

```
file = """he is a good man
she is a beautiful woman
this is a clever student
he is a bad neighbour
they are bad men
She is very beautiful"""

ex = """ good, clever, beautiful, bad,"""

adj = filter(None, ex.split(","))    # removing empty strings from list
# SO ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings

for a in adj:
    if a in file:
        file = file.replace(a, ' ' +'[[' + a.strip() + ']]')    # strip() removes leading or trailing whitespaces

print file
```