# I am hoping someone can help me with a regular expression in Python3 (3.6.2)

Tags: python, regex

I have records being read from a file which are strings of data that I'd like to break into sections.  I new section always begins with `<xxx>` where `xxx` is any three alphabetic characters.  Each section can be a different length.

Listed below is a sample snippet of the data

```
<AAA>q2w *dc<BBB>12sd<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd<DDD> w erdfWED#2w
```

Regardless of the pattern I use, I can't get the string to break as i'd like.  I either get the entire string, or just the section identifier (`<xxx>`) and the very next character.

Listed below are a few patterns that i've tried with the results immediately following:

```
matchLn1 = re.findall('(<\w{3}>.*)','<AAA>q2w *dc<BBB>12sd<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd<DDD> w erdfWED#2w')
['<AAA>q2w *dc<BBB>12sd<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd<DDD> w erdfWED#2w']

matchLn1 = re.findall('(<\w{3}>.*?)','<AAA>q2w *dc<BBB>12sd<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd<DDD> w erdfWED#2w')<br/>
['<AAA>', '<BBB>', '<CCC>', '<DDD>']

matchLn1 = re.findall('(<\w{3}>.+?)','<AAA>q2w *dc<BBB>12sd<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd<DDD> w erdfWED#2w')<br/>
['<AAA>q', '<BBB>1', '<CCC>w', '<DDD> ']

matchLn1 = re.findall('(<\w{3}>.?)','<AAA>q2w *dc<BBB>12sd<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd<DDD> w erdfWED#2w')<br/>
['<AAA>q', '<BBB>1', '<CCC>w', '<DDD> ']
```

I tried a few other patters as well, but the outcome was always the same.  Any/all thoughts would be most welcome.

thank you

Comment: Do you want to *include* the "section separator"? Or not? Please show the *expected* output.

Comment: sorry, good point.  What i'd like (what I hoped for) is: [‘<AAA>q2w *dc’, ’<BBB>12sd’, ‘<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd’, ‘<DDD> w erdfWED#2w')’]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split() like this.

```
import re
text ='<AAA>q2w *dc<BBB>12sd<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd<DDD> w erdfWED#2w'
p = re.compile("<\w{3}>")
print (p.split(text))

['', 'q2w *dc', '12sd', 'wer(4rf) q w ddcd', ' w erdfWED#2w']
```

Updated in response to comments:
You can capture the separators as well like this:

```
import re
text ='<AAA>q2w *dc<BBB>12sd<CCC>wer(4rf) q w ddcd<DDD> w erdfWED#2w'
p = re.compile(r"(<[a-zA-Z]{3}>)")
print (p.split(text))
```

Outputs:

```
['', '<AAA>', 'q2w *dc', '<BBB>', '12sd', '<CCC>', 'wer(4rf) q w ddcd', '<DDD>', ' w erdfWED#2w']
```

Comment: Add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings) logic. Also, put an `r` before the regex string. Nice logic though. You may also want to make `\w` `[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-z]` with `re.I` (I know OP wrote it that way, but they did specify `alphabetic`)

Comment: Thanks Dan, but i'd also like the section identifier in each list entry as well if that's posslbe

Comment: Thanks again.  I guess I can concatenate the appropriate entries to get the section identifier and the associated text into a unique list item.