# converting dictionary values to list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value-store

Suppose I have a dictionary (dict) with keys and values as below:

> print(dict)

```
{'AAA': {'', '111', '222'}, 'BBB': {'222', '999', '555'}}
```

I want to extract the values from the dictionary in the form of a single string, i.e. `type(values) = str`, such as:

```
values = '111', '222', '999', 555'
```

but what I am getting is below under `dict.values()`:

> dict.keys()

```
dict_keys(['AAA', 'BBB'])
```

> dict.values()

```
dict_values([{'', '111', '222'}, {'222', '999', '555'}])
```

How can I achieve the required result?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to do this:

```
In [92]: from itertools import chain

In [93]: dct = {'AAA': {'', '111', '222'}, 'BBB': {'222', '999', '555'}}

In [94]: {x for x in chain(*dct.values()) if x}
Out[94]: {'111', '222', '555', '999'}
```

If you want to convert this output to a single string, just use an `str()` call on it, or use `", ".join(x for x in chain(*dct.values()) if x)`

Comment: That does not outputs a string...adding this will `', '.join(y for y in {x for x in chain(*d.values()) if x})`

Comment: @drec4s I know it doesn't; Op says he wants `values = '111', '222', '999', 555'`, so the requirements aren't clear on that front. But I have made changes so that OP can call `str` on the set to get the values as a single string.

Comment: OP clearly states he wants the output in "the form of a single string"...

Comment: Nevertheless, this is the most efficient way to do it. +1

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after if you want them output as a single string:

```
mydict = {'AAA': {'', '111', '222'}, 'BBB': {'222', '999', '555'}}

out = []
for keys, values in mydict.items():
    [out.append(i) for i in values if i!='']

out = ','.join(set(out))

print(out)

print(type(out))
```

Outputs:

```
555,222,111,999

<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like

```
d = dict()
d[0] = '0'
str(d)
```

?

String manipulations are fairly straightforward after that

Answer (score 0):

Just use `extend` method:

```
values = []
for key in some_dict:
    values.extend(list(some_dict[key]))
```

If you need to delete the empty strings, use:

```
values = list(filter(None, values))
```

See [this SE entry](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings&ved=2ahUKEwjT3vfbjZ_aAhUNGewKHUX1DlUQjjgwAHoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw27yHKdnBgIOmkDT7HtpAki)

Then you can convert it to a tuple if you wish :)

Comment: This won't work, the values are a set not a list. While your approach is in the right direction, you can explore set.add method and correct the code

Comment: Conversion added.

Comment: not to be pedantic, but this won't output the correct result again. The value '222' will repeat twice, which it doesn't in the case of `set`s :)

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do without import any module.

```
dict = {'AAA': {'', '111', '222'}, 'BBB': {'222', '999', '555'}}
result = []
print([[result.append(item) or item for item in one_set if item] for one_set in dict.values()])
print(','.join(result)) #all non '' elements
print(','.join(set(result))) #all non '' and non duplicated elements
```

Output:

```
[['222', '111'], ['222', '999', '555']]
222,111,222,999,555
222,999,555,111
[Finished in 0.181s]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehension in one line :

```
data={'AAA': {'', '111', '222'}, 'BBB': {'222', '999', '555'}}

print(set([k for i,j in data.items() for k in j if k]))
```

output:

```
{'222', '999', '111', '555'}
```