# I'm trying to access the values of this dict but I'm getting the wrong result

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have successfully iterated through a PHP array with Python, i'm stuck with trying to grab values properly in a interger dict

My code is like below :

```
from itertools import chain

listss = {0: {'value': 'Tasty'}, 1: {'value': 'Tasteless'}, 2: {'value': 'Overcooked'}, 3: {'value': 'Undercooked'}, 4: {'value': 'Fresh'}, 5: {'value': 'Not fresh'}}

a = ", ".join(x for x in chain(*listss.values()))

print(a)
```

Output:

```
value, value, value, value, value, value
```

I'm looking for this output:

```
Tasty,Tasteless,Overcooked,Undercooked,Fresh,Not fresh
```

Please help

Comment: i've also tried this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639609/converting-dictionary-values-to-list-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this okay?

```
from itertools import chain

listss = {0: {'value': 'Tasty'}, 1: {'value': 'Tasteless'}, 2: {'value': 'Overcooked'}, 3: {'value': 'Undercooked'}, 4: {'value': 'Fresh'}, 5: {'value': 'Not fresh'}}

a = ", ".join(x['value'] for x in listss.values())

print(a)
```