# Splitting a string but keeping the delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying tokenize some code and would like to keep the delimiter when I split a string.

For example, I would like to keep any occurences of `.`, `(`, `)`, `;`, `~`.

I have been using re.split:

```
line = 'Keyboard.keyPressed();'
re.split(r'([\.\(\)\;\~])', line)
```

However, my current implementation of re.split currently creates some unnecessary empty strings in the array:

```
['Keyboard', '.', 'keyPressed', '(', '', ')', '', ';', '']
```

How can I fix this to exclude the empty strings?

Comment: It is "by design", when matches are consecutive, the empty strings are produced by `re.split`. Just remove empty items from the list.

Comment: Well, in your exact case, you may just use `re.findall(r'[^.();~]+', line)`

Comment: `re.findall(r'[^.();~]+', line)` excludes the delimiters

Comment: Ah, yeah, just include them, `re.findall(r'[^.();~]+|[.();~]', line)`

Comment: gotcha. thanks for the help

Comment: Did it really work? Please check my answer.

Comment: Sup buddy. Do'nt forget to choose one poste as "the answer". ;)

Answer (score 1):

Keep your split simple for clarity and just remove empty strings.

```
import re
line = 'Keyboard.keyPressed();'
split = re.split(r'([\.\(\)\;\~])', line)

cleared = list(filter(None, split))   # <- Add this line

print(cleared)
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datacamp.com/dcl-react.js.gz"></script>

<div data-datacamp-exercise data-lang="python">
  <code data-type="sample-code">
import re
line = 'Keyboard.keyPressed();'
split = re.split(r'([\.\(\)\;\~])', line)
cleared = list(filter(None, split))
print(cleared)
  </code>
</div>
```

See: [how to remove elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'[^.();~]+|[.();~]', line)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E6MBdc/1)

The [*`re.findall`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) will return a list of all matched non-overlapping substrings in the input string, matching the following:

- `[^.();~]+` - 1 or more (due to `+` quantifier) chars other than `.`, `(`, `)`, `;` and `~`
- `|` - or
- `[.();~]` - a single occurrence of `.`, `(`, `)`, `;` or `~`.

See [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/khqTsi):

```
import re
line = 'Keyboard.keyPressed();'
print(re.findall(r'[^.();~]+|[.();~]', line))
# => ['Keyboard', '.', 'keyPressed', '(', ')', ';']
```