# Python 3 split()

Tags: python, split

When I'm splitting a string `"abac"` I'm getting undesired results.

**Example**

```
print("abac".split("a"))
```

Why does it print:

['', 'b', 'c']

instead of

['b', 'c']

Can anyone explain this behavior and guide me on how to get my desired output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a` is the separator, `split()` will return all the words in between the separators without them.

Comment: Because this is how `split` works and is documented: "If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')` returns `['1', '', '2'])`"  https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: `split` and `join` are implemented so that `x.join(s.split(x)) == s` for any string `s` and non-empty string `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@DeepSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace) pointed out *(referring to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split))*

> If sep is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2']).

Therefore I'd suggest using a better delimiter such as a comma `,` or if this is the formatting you're stuck with then you could just use the builtin [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) function as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings) answer, this will remove any "empty" strings if passed `None` as the function.

```
sample = 'abac'
filtered_sample = filter(None, sample.split('a'))
print(filtered_sample)
#['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you split a string in python you keep everything between your delimiters (even when it's an empty string!)

For example, if you had a list of letters separated by commas:

```
>>> "a,b,c,d".split(',')
['a','b','c','d']
```

If your list had some missing values you might leave the space in between the commas blank:

```
>>> "a,b,,d".split(',')
['a','b','','d']
```

The start and end of the string act as delimiters themselves, so if you have a leading or trailing delimiter you will also get this "empty string" sliced out of your main string:

```
>>> "a,b,c,d,,".split(',')
['a','b','c','d','','']

>>> ",a,b,c,d".split(',')
['','a','b','c','d']
```

If you want to get rid of any empty strings in your output, you can [use the filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings).

If instead you just want to get rid of this behavior near the edges of your main string, you can strip the delimiters off first:

```
>>> ",,a,b,c,d".strip(',')
"a,b,c,d"

>>> ",,a,b,c,d".strip(',').split(',')
['a','b','c','d']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `"a"` is what's called a delimiter. It acts as a boundary between the characters before it and after it. So, when you call `split`, it gets the characters before `"a"` and after `"a"` and inserts it into the list. Since there's nothing in front of the first `"a"` in the string `"abac"`, it returns an empty string and inserts it into the list.

Answer (score 0):

`split` will return the characters between the delimiters you specify (or between an end of the string and a delimiter), even if there aren't any, in which case it will return an empty string. (See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for more information.)

In this case, if you don't want any empty strings in the output, you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to remove them:

```
list(filter(lambda s: len(s) > 0, "abac".split("a"))
```