# How to get rid of chunks of whitespace in python?

Tags: python

I have a python file with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlrd
loc = ("/Users/arielkotch/Desktop/file/project/testFile.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    print(sheet.row_values(i))
```

The response I get is as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRLcG.png).

I am new to python, I have tried stripping the whitespace, after cycling through each sub array, but it still appears to have white space.

Comment: Please provide what the input looks like and what you expect the output to look like after removing white space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3845423/953482)

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead, [edit] your question to include a representative (but short) sample, and the expected output.

Comment: I don't think your output is wrong
`l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,5]`
`print(l)`
`#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5]`
that's just how list printing is formatted

Answer (score 0):

For each row, I'm assuming you want to remove excess whitespace but leave a single space where there were many. This can be achieved using the following:

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    i = ' '.join(i.split())
```

This works by splitting on whitespace, then joining the split strings back together. For example:

```
test_string = 'hello        test'
test_string = ' '.join(test_string.split())
>>'hello test'
```