# How to remove ' ' in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm still a noob when it comes to python. I have this list that contains strings. My problem is to remove `''`(empty string) from the list.

I've tried to use `.remove()` in python but it still does not work.

For example, I have a list that contains next data:

```
a = ['', 'word', 'three', '', 'five']
```

I just want the output to be:

```
a = ['word', 'three', 'five']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: `list.remove` only removes the first occurrence of an item if it exists and can raise an error if it's not there. Instead you can use the fact that `bool('')` is False. This means you can do something like `a = ['', 'word', 'three', '', 'five']` then `[ele for ele in a if ele]` where the non-empty strings will evaluate to True and the empty string '' will evaluate to False and be excluded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to rewrite original list missing zero-length strings.

**Code:**

```
a = ['', 'word', 'three', '', 'five']
a = [item for item in a if item]
```

**Output:**

```
['word', 'three', 'five']
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate, there's one line of code which use built-in feature. It's hard to write detailed explanation. Added link to docs.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way using [list generators](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=generator#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions):

`[elem for elem in a if elem]` (This will filter out `None`s, `0` and `False`s)

---

The good short way:

`[elem for elem in a if elem != '']`

---

Using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) built-in function with [lambdas](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression):

`list(filter(lambda e: e != '', a))`

---

The generic way - construct the list of indices to remove and then remove them from the original list:

```
indices_to_remove = []
for i, elem in enumerate(a):
    if elem == '':  # Allows to use a complicated logic
        indices_to_remove.append(i)
for i in sorted(indices_to_remove, reverse=True):
    del a[i]
```

Comment: You can just pass `None` to `filter()`. Quote from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter): `Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression (item for item in iterable if item) if function is None.`

Comment: Than there will be a problem similar to the first - this will filter out Nones, 0 and Falses

Comment: But in question mentioned that `I have this list that contains strings`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like below. `filter` function does that by default.

```
a = ['', 'word', 'three', '', 'five']

print(list(filter(None, a)))
```

Output:

```
['word', 'three', 'five']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `length` of the string and append to the list whose length is more than 1

You can do it by:

```
a = ['', 'word', 'three', '', 'five']
b = []

for x in a:
    if len(x) > 1:
        b.append(a)
```

You can also do it by [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
a = ['', 'word', 'three', '', 'five']
b = [i for i in a if len(i) > 1]
```