# Parser with Regex for finding Words, filtering issue

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string that needs to be parsed I almost got it, but one element gets always excluded. I build the parser with python and the re library.

I have tried it with this regex:

```
([A-Z][a-z]+ [[A-Z][a-z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)|([A-Z]*^\2)
```

Nothing chances when I delete the last group of the regex.

I want to parse for example a string like this:

```
Two WordsThisElseITForTwo Buildings
```

The output should be:

```
[Two Words, This, Else, IT, For, Two Buildings]
```

But the current output is:

```
[Two Words, This, Else, For, Two Buildings]
```

so the block with the uppercase letters gets excluded.

Comment: What is `([A-Z]*^\2)` supposed to match?

Comment: The "IT" sould be matched with it, so the idea

Comment: That `[A-Z]*^\2` is a pattern that does not match any string because `^` matches the string start position and it cannot appear inside a string. Try `re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)?)', text)`

Comment: This is the output it adds the '' too. ```['', 'Two Words', '', 'This', '', 'Else', 'IT', 'For', '', 'Two Buildings', '']```, but sould be fine I can delete those out of the list

Comment: It is not a problem to [remove empty items from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings).

Comment: thanks for helping, but still trying to understand how execly it works

Comment: See my answer below, please let know what is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had modified regex to match your case:

```
([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)?([A-Z]{2})?)
```

I had added the part `[A-Z]{2})` which means match any uppercase character twice.

You can view the same [here](https://regex101.com/r/jvjugh/1/).

Comment: @dominikin9 if this answer helped you upvote and accept it to help future users

Answer (score 0):

That `[A-Z]*^\2` is a pattern that does not match any string because `^` matches the string start position and it cannot appear inside a string.

You may use

```
import re
text = "Two WordsThisElseITForTwo Buildings"
print( list(filter(None, re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)?)', text))) ) 
# or
# print( [x for x in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)?)', text) if x] )
# => ['Two Words', 'This', 'Else', 'IT', 'For', 'Two Buildings']
```

See the [online Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/SIcbxg)

The  `([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)?)` matches 1 or 2 whitespace separated words that start with an uppercase letter and then have 1+ lowercase letters and outputs non-matches between the matched texts, too, because the whole pattern is wrapped with a capturing group. Empty items are filtered out.

**More pattern details**

- `(` - start of Capturing group #1:
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `[a-z]+`  - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?:`  - start of  a non-capturing group:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `[a-z]+`  - 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `)?` - end of the non-capturing group, repeat it 1 or 0 times (it is thus optional).

Comment: I have researched a bit and I think I understand it now. Thanks again for helping, helped a lot.