# How to delete empty strings from a 2d list

Tags: python

I have this 2d list right here :

```
list = [ [1,2,3], [1,'',''], ['','','']]
```

I want to delete every instance of '' in the list, so that the output should look like this:

```
>> [ [1,2,3],[1]]
```

I think that deleting all the ''-s is gonna left me out with this list, so could you please also explain how to get rid of empty lists in 2d lists?

```
>> [ [1,2,3],[1],[]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: You should check for list's length after you did your first iteration, but it's really hard to give an answer if you don't share what you already tried.

Comment: Well, how do you detect an empty list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [[1,2,3], [1,'',''], ['','','']] 
b = [[i for i in item if i != ''] for item in a]
c = [item for item in b if item != []]
print(b)
print(c)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1], []]
[[1, 2, 3], [1]]
```

Comment: could you please explain how this works? b = [[i for i in item if i!='']  for item in a].

Comment: It selects all the none `''` element in the nested list.

Comment: oh, i get it. So what you do is you have a nested loop for items in list, and another loop for the whole list. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

could also use filter:

```
lst = [ [1,2,3], [1,'',''], ['','','']] #don't use list to define a list
list(filter(None,[list(filter(None,l)) for l in lst]))
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner with nested list comprehensions (not very dry though):

```
[[y for y in x if y != ''] for x in list if [y for y in x if y != ''] != []]
# [[1, 2, 3], [1]]
```