# How to filter empty strings and carriage returns from a list?

Tags: python

I'm using the following piece of code to read a file into a list and then filter out all items which are just empty Strings

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
mylist = f.readlines()
f.close();
mylist = list(filter(None, mylist))
```

The problem I've found with `filter`, is that it doesn't filter items which contain a carriage return. Is there a way to filter both empty strings and carriage returns other than iterating across the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: Have you tried the other answers in the duplicates? (the list comprehensions in particular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide filter function instead of using default behavior. Anyway iteration is happening. Use lambda function for simplicity:

```
mylist = list(filter(lambda a: a not in [' ', '', '\n', '\r'], mylist))
```

Comment: @FrancescoMarchioni, no problem

Answer (score 0):

You could do it either one of these two ways (the first, probably slower, one has been commented-out). They both utilize the [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method that all string objects have that removes leading and trailing whitespace, coupled with the fact that the implicit "truthiness" of the resulting string will be determined by whether or not it's empty.

```
from operator import methodcaller

mylist = [
    "abc\n",
    "",
    "def\r",
    " ",
    "ghi\n",
    "\r\n",
    "end\n",
]

#mylist = list(filter(lambda a: a.strip(), mylist))
mylist = list(filter(methodcaller('strip'), mylist))

print(repr(mylist))  # -> ['abc\n', 'def\r', 'ghi\n', 'end\n']
```