# Splitting by consecutive delimiter in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file:

```
John|Hopkins|||31
Sage|Jen|42
```

And I want to read it into python and split by ‘|’

So I want something like:

```
[['John', 'Hopkins', '31'], ['Sage', 'Jen', '42']]

file = open('mytxt.txt', 'r')
file_2 = file.readlines()

lst=[]
for line in file_2:
    line=line.strip('\n')
    line=line.split('|')
    lst.append(line)
print(lst)
```

I’m getting:

```
[['John', 'Hopkins', '', '', '31'], ['Sage', 'Gen', '42']]
```

As seen, there are `''` present in the first list due to consecutive `||`.

How do I modify the split statement to cater for single | and consecutive |||?

Comment: You could just filter out the empty elements if your list. See [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings).

Comment: lst.append([x.strip('|') for x in line.strip().split('|') if x])

Comment: @Mohan there's nothing to strip after it's split

Comment: @cricket_007 : You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use regex to capture one or more

```
import re

with open(‘mytxt.txt’) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.split(r'\|+', line.rstrip()))
```

Comment: I think you should escape `|` in regex pattern, since it is special character in regex syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Add this below your `line=line.split(‘|’)` line

```py
line = [word for word in line if word!='']
```

Comment: You can just do `if word`

Answer (score 1):

You may try filtering out empty values:

```
line = filter(None, s.split("|"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file as a dataframe in and fetch the rows as a list would also do the work.

```
df = pandas.read_csv("mytxt.txt",sep = "|")
rowlist = []
for index,rows in df.iterrows():
    one_row = [rows[column] for column in df.columns]            #get the data as list
    one_row = list(filter(lambda x: str(x) != 'nan', one_row))   #remove null values
    rowlist.append(one_row)                                      #append to main list
```

Output =
`[['John', 'Hopkins', '31'], ['Sage', 'Jen', '42']]`

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is full codes:

- filtering with *list comprehension*

```py
with open('mytext.txt') as f:
    lst = [
        [word for word in line.rstrip().split('|') if word]
        for line in f
    ]
print(lst)
```

- split with regex

```py
import re

with open('mytext.txt') as f:
    lst = [
        re.split(r'\|+', line.rstrip())
        for line in f
    ]
print(lst)
```

outputs are same:

```py
[['John', 'Hopkins', '31'], ['Sage', 'Jen', '42']]
```