# How to remove an empty string from a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I loop through the list like this:

```py
print(b)
for i in list:
    if i == '':
        b.remove(i)
print(b)
```

The empty strings remain in the output:

```
['','123','','','','','1','','1232','']
['123','1','','1232','']
```

How can I remove them all?

Comment: Please include the code as text in the question.

Comment: @GinoMempin Agreed, Voting to reopen so that this question can be closed more appropriately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should not remove while iterating through the list.
Try

```py
b = list(filter(None, b))
```

or

```py
b = [s for s in b if not b == '']
```

or

```py
for i in range( len(b) - 1, -1, -1) :
    if i == '':
        b.del(i)
```

The first and second are more functional solutions,
and the third iterates through the list in reverse.

Comment: Alternatives: `list(filter(None, b))`: `filter(None, ...)` is a special feature which removes all falsy items, also your v0 has the predicate reversed. The third version is not great because `b.remove(i)` will traverse the entire list rather than just remove the item. A "better" imperative version is to iterate in reverse getting the index, and `del` at that index. Doing it backwards ensures items don't move as you modify the list. And I think you can do a reverse removal from lists *while iterating* so you don't have to copy the list beforehand.

Comment: Thank you :) I implemented your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think axolotl's answer is correct, but you can use this for solving your problem too:

```
a = 'a123aaaaa1aa1232a'
b = a.split('a')
lst = []
for i in b:
    if i != '':
        lst.append(i)
print(lst)
```

**Note for being better programmer:** Don't name your variables something easy like `a` and `b`, instead, use a name that make sense with your variable!

Comment: This adds a too many steps, since the solution can easily be one line. I would recommend using a simpler solution since the code will be more readable and easy to understand at quick glance in the future.