# Python regex findall function only returning matchings on groups instead of full string

Tags: python, regex

Given the string **bcacaca**. The regex pattern `b?(.a)*` should match on the whole string. However, a call to `re.findall('b?(.a)*', 'bcacaca')` returns `['ca', '']` as a result. It seems to be only returning the result of matching on the individual groups. What's going on here?

My understanding of `findall` is that it should return all nonoverlapping instances of the regex pattern. In this case it should return `['bcacaca', '']`.

Comment: That's how [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) works: "If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups". If you want to match the whole string, change the group to non-capturing `b?(?:.a)*`

Comment: I believe you are looking for "re.search(...).goroup()"

Comment: @Nick So `?:` is included at the start of every group that you want to mark as non-capturing?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'(b(.a)*)'` as your regex pattern instead. You need `result[0]` in the following example.

```py
import re

result = re.findall('(b(.a)*)', 'bcacaca')
result
```

**Output**:

```sh
[('bcacaca', 'ca')]
```

### A Better Option - Using a *Non-capturing Group*

As @Nick mentioned, a non-capturing group could be used here as follows. Consider the following scenario. For step-by-step explanation see the next section. Also, I encourage you to use this resource: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DafnP1/1).

```py
## Define text and pattern
text = 'bcacaca dcaca dbcaca'
pattern = 'b?(?:.a)*'

## Evaluate regex
result = re.findall(pattern, text)
# output
# ['bcacaca', '', '', 'caca', '', '', 'bcaca', '']

## Drop empty strings from result
result = list(filter(None, result))
# output
# ['bcacaca', 'caca', 'bcaca']
```

#### Explanation for Using a Non-capturing Group

[image]

### References

1. [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)