# How to split the string if special character in string and keep the string in same python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to split the string if special character in string and keep the string in same python?

For Example:

Input:

```
asdf****adec****awd**wer*
```

Needed Output:

```
['asdf','****','adec','****','awd','**','wer','*']
```

My code:

```
import re
a=input().strip()
s=re.findall('[*]|\w+', a)
print(s)
```

My output:

```
['asdf', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'adec', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'awd', '*', '*', 'wer', '*']
```

What mistake i made?? my special characters are printind seperately .

Is there any method without using modules??

Comment: Your ```\w``` has a quantifier ```+```. Try the same thing with your ```*``` group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me your task is better served by [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) rather than `re.findall`, consider that

```
import re
text = "asdf****adec****awd**wer*"
parts = re.split(r'(\*+)',text)
print(parts)
```

output

```
['asdf', '****', 'adec', '****', 'awd', '**', 'wer', '*', '']
```

Note that I used captured group to inform `re.split` to keep separators and also there is empty string in parts and it is considered part after last separators, if this is not acceptable then do

```
parts = [p for p in re.split(r'(\*+)',text) if p]
```

Note: I used so-called raw-string to make escaping easier, as `*` has special meaning if you want literal `*` you must espace it or put in `[` and `]`. See [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) docs for discussion of using raw-strings for `re` needs.

Answer (score 1):

You are matching only a single `*` character in your regex, you need to match all just like you do with `\w` by adding `+`.
Is there any reason behind needing an answer without modules?

Comment: Actually I didn't need answer because of curious only I asked. Thank you :)

Comment: It can be done, but regex allows much cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like `(\*+)` with [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

---

```
import re
test='asdf****adec****awd**wer*'

a=test.strip()
s=list(filter(None, re.split(r'([*]+)', a)))
print(s)
```

Will ouput:

```json
['asdf', '****', 'adec', '****', 'awd', '**', 'wer', '*']
```

Which you can [try online in this demo](https://tio.run/##HYwxCsMwDAB3vSKbJTdk6ewv9AVdTK1QgWsbSRD6eiftLbccN77@7u0@p3xGV1@Uwdk8hWxljxe58Ovvo8R4sMYAkNOv2cxVBhJYqmKOu1RnxUdvvF6fzUYVRw34jDcK65KJCIZKczQCmPME)

---

Using [`filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings) to remove the empty string in the list