# How to split by newline and ignore blank lines using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

Lets say I have this data

```
data = '''a, b, c
d, e, f
g. h, i
  
j, k , l


'''
```

4th line contains one single space, 6th and 7th line does not contain any space, just a blank new line.

Now when I split the same using `splitlines`

```
data.splitlines()
```

I get

```
['a, b, c', 'd, e, f', 'g. h, i', ' ', 'j, k , l', '', '']
```

However expected was just

```
['a, b, c', 'd, e, f', 'g. h, i', 'j, k , l']
```

Is there a simple solution using regular expressions to do this.

*Please note that I know the other way of doing the same by filtering empty strings from the output of `splitlines()`*

I am not sure if the same can be achieved using regex.

When I use regex to split on new line, it gives me

```
import re
re.split("\n", data)
```

Output :

```
['a, b, c', 'd,e,f', 'g. h, i', ' ', 'j, k , l', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty strings from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845423/remove-empty-strings-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi as I said, I don't want to filter later, can you suggest me a regex kind of solution?

Comment: Why are you so insistent on using *re* when you've been offered a perfectly good answer that requires no additional imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with your assessment that filtering is more complicated than using regular expressions. However, if you *really* want to use regex, you could split at *multiple consecutive newlines* like so:

```
>>> re.split(r"\n+", data)
['a, b, c', 'd, e, f', 'g. h, i', 'j, k , l', '']
```

Unfortunately, this leaves an empty string at the end of your list.
To get around this, use `re.findall` to find everything that isn't a newline:

```
>>> re.findall(r"([^\n]+)", data)
['a, b, c', 'd, e, f', 'g. h, i', 'j, k , l']
```

---

Since that regex doesn't work on input with spaces, here's one that does:

```
>>> re.findall(r"^([ \t]*\S.*)$", data, re.MULTILINE)
['a, b, c', 'd, e, f', 'g. h, i', 'j, k , l ']
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/YbGPOk/1)'s the explanation:

```
^([ \t]*\S.*)$
^            $   : Start of line and end of line
 (          )    : Capturing group
  [ \t]*         : Zero or more of blank space or tab (i.e. whitespace that isn't newline
        \S       : One non-whitespace character
          .*     : Zero or more of any character
```

Comment: Yes I need something like your second approach, but your second one gives me `['a, b, c', 'd,e,f', 'g. h, i', ' ', 'j, k , l']`

Comment: I think the OP's data has spaces in the empty lines.

Comment: @Mark yeah, somehow Spyder removed the extra spaces and I thought that regex worked. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @GBDGBDA See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

### List comprehension approach

You can add elements to your list if they are not empty strings or whitespace ones with a condition check.

If the element/line is `True` after stripping it from whitespaces, then it is different from an empty string, thus you add it to your list.

```py
filtered_data = [el for el in data.splitlines() if el.strip()]
# ['a, b, c', 'd, e, f', 'g. h, i', 'j, k , l']
```

### Regexp approach

```py
import re
p = re.compile(r"^([^\s]+.+)", re.M)
p.findall(data)
# ['a, b, c', 'd, e, f', 'g. h, i', 'j, k , l']
```

Comment: As I said, I know I can filter later and I don't wanna do that. I was looking more of a simple approach

Comment: Simpler than this?

Comment: It’s not simpler to use regex. Filtering is a one-liner.

Comment: okay, agreed that is simple, but can someone suggest me a regex solution as well, cuz I don't want to go over my elements again in the loop

Comment: @GBDGBDA What do you mean by "go over my elements **again**"? This answer only iterates over the elements once

Comment: @GBDGBDA I don't know why the regexp approach, but this should be fine.

Comment: May not matter, but the regex will delete lines starting with whitespace.

Comment: @Mark yes its deleting those lines, it does matter

Comment: That's why the regex should not be used in the first place

Comment: @GBDGBDA if the line begins (or ends) with white space, do you want to preserve that whitespace in the results?

Comment: I don't have problem with those lines that actually contains some character other than whitespace, so yes